# Best way to check for collision of multiple objects?

Tags: java, android, collision-detection

I'm making a breakout clone for fun as my first game.  I'm using java and android.

The way I was considering doing it is having all collidable objects register their dimensions into a list, and then iterating through this list with a for loop each frame to check for collisions.

The outer loop would first be a simple fast check that would determine the distance, and if the ball is close enough to an object it would go into a more tasking detection.

Comment: There are like a bajillion tutorials on this. And yes, there is often *Broad-phase* (aka "fast/far") and *Narrow-phase* (aka "close/precise") collision detection in play. The different kinds of collision detection - not all of which are appropriate for all tasks - are quite varied and some basic background reading would be a good start.